# React: How can I change a component which has rendered to pass to a sibling component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which is rendering a Product:

```
 const Product = ({
  className,
  count = 1,
  images,
  isAdded,
  isFeatured,
  key,
  onClick,
  onDecrement,
  onIncrement,
  price,
  title
}) => {
     <>
      {modalActive && (
        <Modal
          isModalActive={isModalActive}
          key={key}
          finalPrice={finalPrice}
        />
      )}
      <div className={productClasses}>
        <img
          className={styles.image}
          onClick={() => isModalActive(true)}
          src={imageSrc}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className={styles.details}>
          <div className={styles.text}>
            <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>
            <span className={styles.price}>${finalPrice}</span>
          </div>
          {isInCart ? (
            <Quantity
              onIncrement={onIncrement}
              onDecrement={onDecrement}
              count={count}
            />
          ) : (
            <Button
              className={styles.addButton}
              disabled={isAdded}
              onClick={onClick}
            >
              {isAdded ? 'Added' : 'Add to Bag'}
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

You can see above there is a sibling which is a `<Modal/>`, I'm thinking I could just pass that div into a component

```
const ReusableProduct = ({product}) => <>{product}</>;


const Product = ({
  className,
  count = 1,
  images,
  isAdded,
  isFeatured,
  key,
  onClick,
  onDecrement,
  onIncrement,
  price,
  title
}) => {
const div ({ className,
  count = 1,
  images,
  isAdded,
  isFeatured,
  key,
  onClick,
  onDecrement,
  onIncrement,
  price,
  title}) = <div>...product</div>
   return ( 
     <>
      {modalActive && (
        <Modal
          isModalActive={isModalActive}
          key={key}
          product={div}
        />
      )}
      <ReusableProduct product={div}
    </>
  );
```

Is there a way to get that same component into the `<Modal/>`. Reason being—I want the same data, but I need to position differently in the Modal...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want both the modal and the product to have same props, then you can have one common parent wrapping them both .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recompose your components like this:

```
 const ProductWrapper = (props) => {
     <>
      {modalActive && (
        <Modal
          isModalActive={isModalActive}
          key={key}
          finalPrice={finalPrice}
        >
          <Product {..props} />
        </Modal>
      )}
      <Product {..props} />
    </>
  );

 const Product = ({
  className,
  count = 1,
  images,
  isAdded,
  isFeatured,
  key,
  onClick,
  onDecrement,
  onIncrement,
  price,
  title
}) => {
      <div className={productClasses}>
        <img
          className={styles.image}
          onClick={() => isModalActive(true)}
          src={imageSrc}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className={styles.details}>
          <div className={styles.text}>
            <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>
            <span className={styles.price}>${finalPrice}</span>
          </div>
          {isInCart ? (
            <Quantity
              onIncrement={onIncrement}
              onDecrement={onDecrement}
              count={count}
            />
          ) : (
            <Button
              className={styles.addButton}
              disabled={isAdded}
              onClick={onClick}
            >
              {isAdded ? 'Added' : 'Add to Bag'}
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
  );
```

**UPD**
If you need some props to be different in `Product` that used in modal you can make it like this:

```
 const ProductWrapper = (props) => {
     <>
      {modalActive && (
        <Modal
          isModalActive={isModalActive}
          key={key}
          finalPrice={finalPrice}
        >
          <Product {..props} className="modalProduct" />
        </Modal>
      )}
      <Product {..props} />
    </>
 }
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This makes sense, but let's say in the `<Product />` nested in the modal, what if I wanted to  change a few values in the component?

Comment: See an update. Am i understood you correctly?

Comment: Indeed! I want to pass different `classNames` so I can change the layout of the Product, because the positioning of elements are different in the `<Modal />` Thank you!